# I can't display results line by line with "diff" on unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, diff

**SUMMARY**
I'm using "diff" on my linux shell to compare two txt files.
My files are like this:
*file1.txt*

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

*file2.txt*

```
test6
test7
test8
test9
test10
```

**ISSUE**
I use this command `diff test1.txt test2.txt`
And it displays

```
1,5c1,5
< test1
< test2
< test3
< test4
< test5
---
> test6
> test7
> test8
> test9
> test10
```

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE**

```
1,5c1,5
< test1
> test6
---
< test2
> test7
---
< test3
> test8
---
< test4
> test9
---
< test5
> test10
```

I tried my best to test with all parameters of 'diff' but I not be able to get what I want.

Comment: Do you maybe want side-by-side? How are you going to process the output?

Comment: @BenjaminW. The same as side by side but in vertical view with 1 column as my example.
side-by-side displays me:
`test1                                 | test6
test2                                 | test7
test3                                 | test8
test4                                 | test9
test5                                 | test10`

Comment: Whats the output if you have a matching line in the middle? Is this always sorted?

Comment: did you try `sdiff test1.txt test2.txt`

Comment: `git` has some tweaks for "minimal hunks" but I don't think this is in `diff` but in some other external diff tool.

Comment: @SriniV Nope tested with sdiff

Comment: `comm -3 test1.txt test2.txt` is a close match to your needs and similarily `diff <(nl file1) <(nl file2)`

Comment: @SriniV Not the same cause I want to compare with long lines, and it is better for me to compare in vertical view than horizontal with a line in a middle

Comment: I would suggest to use `awk` scripting instead of `diff`

Comment: With a bit of scripting: `diff  -y test1.txt test2.txt | tr '|' '\n' | sed -E "s,^[ \t]+(.+$),\1\n---,g"`

Comment: Note that it's not really future-proof, for example it wouldn't work well if you had `|` characters in the files.

Comment: I've just test your command, it's good with words like 'test1', 'test2' etc.. but witha big lign the "side-by-side" cut it...